# HTML Multi-Dimensional Array

Tags: php, arrays

In the code below only the values from the last two forms are displayed. What could I be doing wrong?

```
<form action="" method="post">

<input name="fields[edu][name][]" /> 
<input name="fields[edu][age][]"/> 
<br/><br/>

<input name="fields[edu][name][]" /> 
<input name="fields[edu][age][]"/> 

<br/><br/>
<input name="fields[edu][name][]" /> 
<input name="fields[edu][age][]"/> 

<br/><br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
```

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    print_r($_POST['fields']);

    foreach($_POST['fields'] as $field){
        echo '<br/>';
        echo 'Hello your name is : '.$field['name'];
        echo '<br/>';
        echo 'Hello your age is : '.$field['age'];
    }
}
```

**Update:** What would be the best way to echo the values from the array? I've tried several methods none works

Comment: You're using the same name each time. If you want them to be arrays, you should use something like `<input name="fields[edu][name][]" />`

Comment: Because you name each array `[edu]` they get overwritten when sent to the PHP interpreter.  You will need to name them edu1, edu2, edu3 so the foreach will drop them out properly.

Comment: @rickdenhaan ,  I made an update to the question. How would I echo the values efficiently?

Comment: @Forbs what I need the fields for would require them being the same

Comment: the 2nd two, `age` and `name` can be the same,  but if you set `edu` as the same, then it will overwrite when it hits the php processor.  Why do they have to be the same? they aren't even referenced in the foreach.  If you try setting up a 3 element array with a key of `edu` you will end up with a 1 element array

Comment: @dsaviour in case you haven't got it yet, you can loop like this if you keep `edu` the same: `foreach ($_POST['fields']['edu']['name'] as $index => $name) { $age = $_POST['fields']['edu']['age'][$index]; }`

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="" method="post">

<input name="fields[edu0][name][]" /> 
<input name="fields[edu0][age][]"/> 
<br/><br/>

<input name="fields[edu1][name][]" /> 
<input name="fields[edu1][age][]"/> 

<br/><br/>
<input name="fields[edu2][name][]" /> 
<input name="fields[edu2][age][]"/> 

<br/><br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
```